# Xdebug always waiting for incoming connection with idekey with PhpStorm and WAMP Server

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've read and tried all the solutions concerning this question, I successfully installed `Xdebug` and when I type `php --v` on cmd I get:

> Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with Xdebug v2.9.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans

I added the Xdebug configuration under `php.ini`:

```
[XDebug]

zend_extension = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_port="9000"
```

I edited the Debug/Run configuration like exactly mentioned in the tutorials and StackOverflow. My problem is that the the debugger is always waiting for incoming connection with ide key '(random number)'.

Am I missing something? Any advice could help, thanks.

Comment: Have you configured your IDE for port 9000 and idekey? How do you pass idekey to the server?

Comment: Hi, no I did not configured my IDE for Idekey and I did not pass it to the server. I dont know how to do so, please tell me if you have an idea about setting it and thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the url you are testing ? is it localhost ? some specific local domain name ? are you debugging scripts in CLI mode ?

Comment: Hi Gharbi, yes localhost

Comment: Please show Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser.

Comment: @LazyOne         xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version  2.6.1
IDE Key  DESKTOP-9JCPCGB$

Comment: @RomelouStriga That is not what I have asked for. But it's fine -- you know better what you need and what you are doing.